# when is the memory allocated for variables in java(compile time or run time)?

Tags: java

In  C&c++ static variables are assigned memory during compile time itself.so I want to know when will the memory allocation to variables takes place in Java ?

Answer (score 0):

Java source files are compiled into `.class` files. And `.class` files are not really comparable to binaries compiled from C/C++. So your question doesn't really make sense I'm afraid.

The memory to hold the value of a static variable in Java is most likely allocated when the class is loaded (but this is VM implementation specific I would assume).

But to give you a direct answer to your question, I would say no, memory is not allocated for static variables during compilation of a Java program.

Comment: sir my question is when will the actual memory space to variables allocated in java i,e during compile time or static time??

Comment: If you consider your question answered, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the answers so we get a closure on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Memory for static variables (class variables) is allocated during class loading to JVM.
Memory for object variables is allocated while creating new objects (this is responsibility of new keyword in java).